# jquery accordion with tabs

Tags: jquery

Being a newbie I have read forums and posts but still can't work out how to have tabs inside accordions. I'm using the following. No Ajaxed content.

jQuery UI Example Page

```
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion").dialog({
                open: function(){
                    $("#tabs").tabs();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo page css*/
        body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
        .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
        #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
        #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
        ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
        ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
    </style>    
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Accordion -->
    <h2 class="demoHeaders">Accordion</h2>
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>

            <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
    </div>

        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
            <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
            <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a few errors preventing this from working, [all fixed in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4wSqn/).

- IDs must be unique, your Tab IDs, e.g `id="tabs"` need to be `class="tabs"`, also each set needs it's own IDs, for example the second should start with: `<a href="#tabs-4">` and the corresponding `<div id="tabs-4">` below and so on.
- The accordion headers and `<div>` for content needs to be siblings, so the `<h2>` elements should be beside the content `<div>` elements for the accordion.
- Change your jQuery to use [`.accordion()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) for accordion instead of `.dialog()` (this is a separate plugin).

Your jQuery should look like this in the end (notice `.tabs` using a class selector):

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
$(".tabs").tabs();​
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much for your help Nick, I understand where I went wrong. You have saved me another nights worth of pottering around the internet! Thank you.

Comment: @John - Welcome, if you had other issues with the question please comment :)  If not, please make sure mark the answer as accepted to "close-out" the question....also make sure to do this on future questions as well

Comment: Thank you for that I have it working on its own but when I insert it onto my page the styles and the functionality disappears. I have narrowed it down to a script file that I import its my custom script file thats initiates a lot of my jquery. It can be seen at   http://jsfiddle.net/4wSqn/3/ as you'll notice I have put your accordion and tabs jquery code at the end of the function which breaks the accordion and tabs. But if I move it towards the top, it works. Why is that have I messed up the syntax?